# Is there a way to stop my Razor laptop from going to sleep mode randomly?

Tags: windows-10

As I use my Razor laptop, the screen shuts off as if in sleep mode. I don't know why this is happening and sometimes this happens when I am not using/touching the laptop.

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question. Try [su].

Comment: oh, sorry. Thank you for the link to super user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't remember it correctly, but I think I read it on reddit about similar issue. It may have to do something about the power/sleep button problem. You can go to the windows settings and disable the power button- as in, change its function to "do nothing", from the default sleep option. Hope this helps.
(as the other user mentioned, this site is mainly for programming related questions)

Comment: Sorry about asking it here. Thanks for this, I tried it. I will have to wait and see if this works. So far so good though.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that you know to be off-topic. It will likely lead to down votes, as it has (not mine...)

Comment: I dint know that, thanks David.